# pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin() is very slow , how can i make my code faster?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, pandas-groupby

i am trying to do same action as SQL group by and take min value :

```
select id,min(value) ,other_fields...
from table
group by ('id')
```

i tried :

```
dfg = df.groupby('id', sort=False)
idx = dfg['value'].idxmin()
df = df.loc[idx, list(df.columns.values)]
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html
but line 2 the idxmin() is taking more than half hour on ~4M columns in df where the group by takes less than 1 second , what am i missing is it suppose to take that long ? how can make this process faster ? will it be faster in pure SQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use alternative with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = df.sort_values(by=['value']).drop_duplicates('id', keep='first')
```

Comment: This was a marvellous suggestion for me in something I was doing this week. I was very pleased to find this answer! I managed to reduce my processing time by several hours on a dataset of 100s of millions of rows.